# Sorting objects according to a specific rule

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

In Javascript I need to order objects in an array according to type. Each type has a higher priority, so an object with the type "wipe" should have the highest priority therefore be at the front of the array(index=0).

What would be the best way to sort these objects? Is there a builtin function that can do this?

For eg:

```
function sortObjects( objs )
{
   // objs is an unsorted array of objects 
   var animPriority = {"wipe": 1, "fly": 2, "iris": 3, "flip": 4, "cube": 5, "blur": 6, "zoom": 7, "fade": 8, "glow": 9, "rotate": 10};

   for (var i=0; i<objs.length; i++)
       if (objs[i].type == "wipe")
          // bubblesort/bubbleswap element in objs[0] with objs[i]????
          // a bubble sort doesn't seem efficient though?
}
```

Comment: Just pass a comparer function to the native `.sort` function.

Comment: Who would have thought such a simple question would generate such a discussion, and a collection of half-baked answers to boot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's `array.sort` method expects a compare function, simply pass this function:

```
function compareFunc(a,b) { return animPriority[a.type] - animPriority[b.type]; }
```

Answer (score 16):

This could be the solution you are looking for:

```
objs.sort(function(a,b){
    var order = ["wipe", "fly", "iris", "flip", "cube",
        "blur", "zoom", "fade", "glow", "rotate"];
    return order.indexOf(a.type) - order.indexOf(b.type);
});
```

It works exactly as requested. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVdsA/) for a proof.

The solution uses `sort()` method of `Array` class, passing callback to it, which allows for custom comparison. In this case comparison is based on the position of `.type` property of compared elements within `order` array.

Comment: Would it be better to create the function like this? `var myFunc = function(a,b) {// function body };`?  Wouldn't the function and array be created anew with each call to sort using your example?

Comment: @Paul: No offense, but think about it for a while :) It all depends on how you use it and the answer to your question is more complex. Important issues here are: 1) closures (where `myFunc` / anonymous function is accessible), 2) how many times `objs` array is going to be sorted, 3) do you care with namespace polluting. Depending on how & where you assign function to `myFunc`, the answer is different.

Comment: @Paul: In other words `var myFunc = function(a,b){/* code */}; objs.sort(myFunc);` has exact same effect as `objs.sort(function(a,b){/* code */});`, except the first solution pollutes the namespace unnecessarily. Unless, of course, there is something more than simple assignement before usage ;)

Comment: Thanks...JavaScript isn't my "native" language, and while I've worked with closures before, sometimes the subtleties escape me. Did I read your code correctly, that each instance of `objs` will get its own copy of the comparison function? Or is something else going on that I'm missing?

Comment: @Paul: I did not look into the code of JS engines such as V8, but I believe the function is being passed at run time, to the specific method. It does not mean that after this call all the objects (or `objs` arrays) will behave the same way just by calling `.sort()`. The way `.sort()` works depends on the argument (a callback) - and this is the purpose of the callback. You can encounter similar concept in different languages (Python, PHP etc., to name some).

Comment: How could this be adapted to work with elements outside of the order array? I'm not certain what's in the main array but I do know which elements should be at the top if they appear.

Comment: @cronoklee: This solution requires you to first determine the order array. So you need to first create order array, and then sort. Sorting when you don't really know the order yet, would be much more complex, and depending on the exact requirements, may involve treating "inserted" order items differently, assigning them different custom "weights" instead of just looking up 0-based position of them in order array.

Comment: @cronoklee: There is also easier solution. When you detect element, that has to be at the top, instead of searching for its index in an array use `-1` where you would use its index. That should work like a special rule, putting these special elements at the top of the list.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty straightforward in JavaScript:

First, put your objects in an array, e.g. `myArray`.

Next, write a function that takes objects and returns a value less than 0 if the first object should appear before the second object in the array, 0 if the two objects are equal for purposes of the sort, or a value greater than 0 if the second object should appear before the first object in the array.  For example:

```
function myOrderFunc(a, b)
{
  // if a should come before b, return a negative value
  // if b should come before a, return a positive value
  // if they are equally ranked in the sort order, return 0
}
```

Finally, call `myArray.sort(myOrderFunc)`.  This will sort the objects in place in your array.  If you need a more detailed example using your specific data just ask.